# Are tantalums good for PIC Vcap?

Tags: pic, capacitor, voltage-regulator, esr, tantalum

I understand that ceramics are good at ESR but would like to know if tantalum would suffice for my application.

Some 16 bit PICs require a >4.7uf cap (10uf recommended) low ESR cap for their internal regulator. The datasheet doesn't specify the type of capacitor but only says low ESR.

I have successfully used a 10uf ceramic cap with [PIC24EP64GP202](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en556205);
*Can I use a tantalum cap instead?*

*Does DOM (Date of Manufacture) of the caps matter in this regard?*

*Does age (in-line use period) of a tantalum capacitor matter?* Although I'm not going to use a used capacitor but would like to know this for curiosity.

*Do tantalum capacitors age? Shelf life? In-use life?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PIC's datasheet says less than 1 Ohm ESR and it specifically mentions tantalum as being OK.

> The regulator provides power to the core from the other VDD pins. A
> low-ESR (less than 1 Ohm) capacitor (such as tantalum or ceramic) must
> be connected to the VCAP pin (Figure 27-1). This helps to maintain the
> stability of the regulator. The recommended value for the filter
> capacitor is provided in Table 30-5 located in Section 30.0
> “Electrical Characteristics”.

https://web.archive.org/web/20140809183203/http://www.avx.com/docs/Catalogs/techsum.pdf

Has a lot of information about tantalum capacitor failure modes.  It's an interesting read.

**Steady-State**

> Tantalum Dielectric has essentially no wear out mechanism and in
> certain circumstances is capable of limited self healing. However,
> random failures can occur in operation. The failure rate of Tantalum
> capacitors will decrease with time and not increase as with other
> electrolytic capacitors and other electronic components.

IMO tantalum are fine for this application. I wouldn't be concerned about age unless you have some very special requirements.